# Magento 2 | Display message above payment-method in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

how can I show a message above the payment-methods in checkout?

Comment: check my answer solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy file to your theme and add message.

File path:

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/payment-methods/list.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
 -->
<div if="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="items payment-methods">
    <div class="your-message">YOUR MESSAGE DISPLAY HERE</div>
    <div repeat="foreach: paymentGroupsList, item: '$group'"
         class="payment-group">
        <div if="getRegion($group().displayArea)().length"
             translate="getGroupTitle($group)"
             class="step-title"
             data-role="title">
        </div>
        <each args="data: getRegion($group().displayArea), as: 'method'" render=""/>
    </div>
</div>
<div ifnot="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="no-payments-block"
     translate="'No Payment Methods'">
</div>
```

Run command:

> rm -rf pub/static/frontend/
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

[image]

Comment: can you make it look like a warning?

Comment: @L.Klmn you can add css class or html related to that.

Comment: can I use php within the html?

Comment: No, you can't use PHP but you can do it by knockout js.

Answer (score 1):

The Simple way:

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/onepage.html**

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('authentication') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('progressBar') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('estimation') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->

<div class="opc-wrapper">
    <div class="custom-message">YOUR MESSAGE HERE</div>
    <ol class="opc" id="checkoutSteps">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('steps') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
    </ol>
</div>

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('sidebar') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: How can we display a link to account dashboard if there is no payment method available? like No Payment method available <a href="/customer/account">Here</a>.