# Magento 2: I want to show custom messgae based on product added in cart in payment step

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, magento2.3.0

In Magento 1, there is custom message based on product id, added in cart as below:-

[image]

Same I want to show in Magento 2.3.

For static message I follow [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228694/magento-2-display-message-above-payment-method-in-checkout) article.

Please help me how to add condition based on product ids in checkout .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="beforeMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom_block" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">SR_MagentoCommunity/js/view/custom-block</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/js/view/custom-block.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, ko, Component, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'SR_MagentoCommunity/custom-block'
        },
        isVisibleFirstBlock:  ko.observable(false),
        isVisibleSecondBlock: ko.observable(false),
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var items = quote.getItems();
            var hasProductInCart = 0;
            $.each(items, function(index, item) {
                if (item.product_id == 14) {
                    hasProductInCart = 1;
                }
            }.bind(this));

            var regionId = 0;
            var self = this;
            quote.shippingAddress.subscribe(function (address) {
                regionId = address.regionId;
                if (hasProductInCart && (regionId == 12)) {
                    self.isVisibleFirstBlock(true);
                } else {
                    self.isVisibleSecondBlock(true);
                }
            });

            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/template/custom-block.html

```
<!-- ko if: (isVisibleFirstBlock()) -->
    <div>
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Custom Message 1'"></span>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: (isVisibleSecondBlock()) -->
    <div>
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Custom Message 2'"></span>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I also want to check region id with product id, how to get region id here. Thanks

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Accept this answer, that will help other

Comment: Already upvote for your answer